# Android security document comparable to Apple's security document?

Tags: android

Is there an Android security document comparable to Apple's [Security Document](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) (PDF)?  Does such a comprehensive document not apply because Android is only the OS and Apple makes the hardware and the OS and tightly couples them?  Would such a document have to be made or customized per each manufacturer for each model handset of Android device?

NOTE: This document, while technical in nature, is not written by or for programmers.  I have found that most Google documentation is by and for programmers.  I can read and write code, but I'm not looking for code.  This [blog post](http://nelenkov.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html) quickly dives into code and is an example of what I am referring to that dives straight into code and APIs.

I have found recent information and technical details, but they are referring to now-old versions of Android, or referring to Android Lollipop when it was still prerelease.

- [Which android devices have optimized encryption hardware?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65444/which-android-devices-have-optimized-encryption-hardware)
- [Canonical explanation of Android Encryption and Vulnerabilities](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/137389/canonical-explanation-of-android-encryption-and-vulnerabilities)
- [Android L encryption vs. iOS 8 encryption](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68454/android-l-encryption-vs-ios-8-encryption)

Answer (score 5):

Official documentation on Android security can be found [on the AOSP site](http://source.android.com/security/index.html). However, I would expect a non-programmer to only understand a subset of that documentation.